# Why doesn't regex \s match a single space?

Tags: c#, regex

I feel like I'm going insane.  Why doesn't the pattern `\s` match a single space character?  See below or in [this pad](http://csharppad.com/gist/4711c84300e54d050292).

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(@" ", " "));
// True
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(@"\s", " "));
// False!?
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(" ", @"\s"));   // true`

Comment: Why are people downvoting and voting this as off topic?  This is a "[specific programming problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)".  I *genuinely* couldn't figure this out!  Though I feel like a dope considering how simple the answer is, I really don't see why this kind of question should be discouraged.

Comment: Because it's a simple typo and not likely to be of use to anybody else. See the close reason `This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.`

Comment: That justifies the votes to close, but the downvotes are pretty discouraging.

Comment: I think that people don't believe you when you say *"I* genuinely *couldn't figure this out!"*, so the downvotes are probably because of RTFM. I think you're right though, closing is fair enough, downvote is not necessary for this question.

Comment: Ugh.  Well I'm being honest. The MSDN [regex quick reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and the [regex class docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) have been open, as well as [CSharpPad](http://csharppad.com/gist/4711c84300e54d050292) and the [CShell REPL](http://cshell.net/).  I read and tried for 15 or 20 minutes before narrowing it down to a simple, reproducible example (see my snippet).  It was a simple, honest mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The order of the arguments is incorrect. The signature of the [`Regex.IsMatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0(v=vs.110).aspx) is:

```
public static bool IsMatch(
    string input,
    string pattern
)
```